# Using Robotium when only having APK

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I found Robotium for about one week ago,  its a really nice tool.
I an new in android testing and Java programming.
Please I will like to know if there is  any  existing solution or
example to make use of Robotium for pre-installed application like
Android Phone Dialer and Contacts ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From the Robotium Guide for using the apk with signed and unsigned

https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForAPKFiles

Answer (score 1):

From the Robotium guide:

> With Robotium it is possible to run test cases on applications that
>   are pre-installed.     For this to work you need to resign the
>   pre-installed application with the same certificate signing of your
>   test project. That requires you to have a rooted phone as you must
>   have    access to the /system/app folder on the device.
>
> Observe that some pre-installed applications do not function properly
>   when re-installed   with a new certificate signing. An example is the
>   contacts application (Contacts.apk) that does not show up when
>   re-signed.
>
> Details There are some steps that you need to follow to make it work:
>
> 1. Log in as root: adb root
> 2. Remount: adb remount
> 3. adb pull /system/app/X.apk (Replace X with the name of the application)
> 4. Resign X.apk so that it has the same certificate signing as the test project
> 5. adb pull /data/system/packages.xml
> 6. Open packages.xml and remove:
>
> ..... 
>   7. Push packages.xml back to device: adb push packages.xml /data/system
>
> 1. Restart your device
> 2. Push the resigned X.apk back to the device: adb push X.apk /system/app
> 3. Follow the [details section](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForAPKFiles)